# Dafny partial functions and "value does not satisfy the subset constraints" error

Tags: dafny

I'm trying to use partial functions for the first time, and am having trouble making sense of the error message.

```
predicate b_is_fa(a: nat, b: nat, f: nat-->nat)
    requires f.requires(a)
{
    b == f(a)
}

lemma checking(a: nat, offset: nat)
    ensures b_is_fa(a+offset, a, x requires x >= offset => x - offset)
{
}
```

This produces the error:

`value does not satisfy the subset constraints of 'nat --> nat' (possible cause: it may have read effects)Verifier`

Any suggestions for what the problem is and how I can go about fixing it?

**Update:**
I can resolve this error by adding a nat->nat subtraction function.

```
function sub(a: nat, b: nat): nat
    requires b <= a
{
    a - b
}
```

and then using that function in my lambda function.

```
lemma checking(a: nat, offset: nat)
    ensures b_is_fa(a+offset, a, x requires x >= offset => sub(x, offset))
{
}
```

I think what was happening is that the subtraction was producing an 'int' and then dafny was having trouble getting back to the 'nat'.

Comment: You can add `x:nat` for the parameter of the lambda, though that doesn't resolve the issue.  It looks to me like a compiler bug actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the closure you pass in argument has the type `int --> int` when the function it accepts is  `nat --> nat`. nat is a subset of int, so it does not type check.

You might want to write this instead to force the types to be nat:

```
    ensures b_is_fa(a+offset, a, (x: nat) requires x >= offset => var r: nat := x - offset; r)
```